# Объясните код на питоне

Tags: python, математика

Это решение задачи на полуразность чисел, но я не понимаю сам код, а особенно 3 строчку. Кто нибудь может мне объяснить этот код?

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
x, y = (a + b), (a - b) / 2
if a > b:
    print(x, y)
elif a < b:
    print(y, x)
else:
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: А что именно здесь вам непонятно? Переменная x получает сумму чисел, y — полуразность, вывод зависит от соотношения чисел a и b.

Comment: А условие задачи будет?

Comment: Я не понимаю зачем здесь (a+b)

Comment: Условие задачи просто вычислить полуразность чисел

Comment: Так это вы знаете условие задачи :) И правильно она решена или нет, а не мы. Мы видим только, что этот код *делает*. А что *должен* — вы не говорите.

Comment: @Harry так ТС и не спрашивает о правильности или о должности. Это уже вы додумали )

Comment: @Kromster  Тогда чем его не устроил мой первый комментарий? Чем *Переменная x получает сумму чисел, y — полуразность* отличается от принятого ответа? Его "*Я не понимаю зачем здесь (a+b)*" мне говорит о том, что в условии сумму искать не требуется, и он не понимает, зачем ее ищут.

Comment: @Harry а ответ Инсолора - устроил // развожу руками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разбираем по частям:

```
x, y = (a + b), (a - b) / 2
```

это то же самое что

```
(x, y) = ((a + b), (a - b) / 2)
```

Здесь элементам кортежа (tuple) слева присваиваются элементы из кортежа справа (прием называется "распаковка"), т.е. получается, что:

```
x = (a + b)
y = (a - b) / 2
```

И без "вывертов" ваш код можно записать так:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

x = a + b
y = (a - b) / 2

if a > b:
    print(x, y)
elif a < b:
    print(y, x)
else:
    print(a, b)
```